# Trying to run multiple instances of sklearn KMeans in parallel

Tags: python, scikit-learn, multiprocessing, k-means

I am trying to run multiple instances of Kmeans ([from sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)) in parallel. I have the following code:

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    kmeans_per_k = [executor.submit(KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=42).fit(features)) for k in range(1,16)]
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(kmeans_per_k):
        f = f.result()
```

This gives me the following error

```
TypeError: 'KMeans' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because the fit function returns the KMeans object. The ProcessPoolExecutor expects a function in the submit method. What you are doing is essentially doing the fit when preparing the parameter to submit. You probably want something along the lines of:

```py
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    kmeans_per_k = [executor.submit(KMeans(n_clusters=k, random_state=42).fit, features) for k in range(1,16)]
    for f in concurrent.futures.as_completed(kmeans_per_k):
        f = f.result()
```